# issue with executing runnable jar file on windows 10

Tags: java, executable-jar

I packed my working app in eclipse using file/export/runnablejar file.
Although in Eclipse I have no error I cannot run my app on Windows level.

I use cmd to track if any erro ,here's what it returns:
cmd -- > java -jar wypozyczalnia.jar

```
progress: 0.1
Value@ :0.1
progress: 0.2
Value@ :0.2
progress: 0.3
Value@ :0.3
progress: 0.4
Value@ :0.4
progress: 0.5
Value@ :0.5
progress: 0.6
Value@ :0.6
progress: 0.7
Value@ :0.7
progress: 0.8
Value@ :0.8
progress: 0.9
Value@ :0.9
progress: 1.0
Value@ :1.0
BEFORE_START
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name bundles.messages, locale en
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
    at pl.moja.wypozyczalnia.utils.FxmlUtils.getResourceBundle(FxmlUtils.java:30)
    at pl.moja.wypozyczalnia.utils.FxmlUtils.fxmlLoader(FxmlUtils.java:13)
    at pl.moja.wypozyczalnia.Main.load(Main.java:48)
    at pl.moja.wypozyczalnia.Main.start(Main.java:37)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application pl.moja.wypozyczalnia.Main
```

Do you know what is the root cause?

Comment: The error suggest you are trying to load a resource bundle `bundles.messages`, and it can't be found. It is probably not present in your jar file. However, without a [mcve] that is hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: The cause is `MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name bundles.messages, locale en`. Pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: yes but for sure I have folder bundles in my app..

Comment: https://github.com/tomekcm4/wypozyczalnia

Comment: You need to tell Eclipse what to do with your resource files. I've only used Eclipse a little, several years ago, but I think you need to place your resources in a resource directory and tell Eclipse that it's a resource directory, so that it will include the file in the jar.

Comment: at the same time app is running in eclipse

Comment: yes, true: https://imgur.com/a/FChvr3H

Comment: if you have eclipse can you check if you have the same when creating running jar?

Comment: I don't have Eclipse, but have you checked whether the file messages.properties and the bundles directory exist in the jar file?

Comment: Hang on a minute, the error message says it's looking for locale en, but your bundles directory only has a file for locale pl.

Comment: locale en is default, as bundles.messages